# stubs MailChimp api call for functional testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mailchimp, ruby-mocha

I'm trying to test a MailChimp subscription to an specific list:

test/functional/some_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SomeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "invalid signup" do
    Gibbon.stubs(:subscribe).raises(Gibbon::MailChimpError, 500)
    post :signup, {:EMAIL => "invalid_email"}
    assert_response 500
  end

  test "valid signup" do
    Gibbon.stubs(:subscribe).returns(200)
    post :signup, {:EMAIL => "my_email@something.com"}
    assert_response 200
  end
end
```

controllers/some_controller.rb

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def signup
    begin
      gb = Gibbon::API.new
      resp = gb.lists.subscribe(
        :id => ENV["key_list"],
        :email => {:email => "#{params[:EMAIL]}"}
      )
      render :status => :ok, :json => resp
    rescue Gibbon::MailChimpError => e
      render :status => :internal_server_error, :json => {error: e, message: e.message}
    end
  end
end
```

But I think that I missing something here because the tests are passing but they are doing a call to the API, because as I'm using my email for testing purposes I receive the email confirmation from MailChimp each time that I run:

```
"rake test:functionals"
```

And if I try to run:

```
Gibbon.any_instance.stubs(:subscribe).raises(Gibbon::MailChimpError, 500)
```

or

```
Gibbon.any_instance.stubs(:subscribe).returns(200)
```

I get the following errors:

```
test_invalid_signup(SomeControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method 'any_instance' for Gibbon:Module

test_valid_signup(SomeControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method 'any_instance' for Gibbon:Module
```

**EDIT I**

I was able to use any_instance method doing this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class NewsletterControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "invalid signup" do
    gb = Gibbon::API.new
    gb.any_instance.stubs(:subscribe).raises(Gibbon::MailChimpError, 500)
    post :signup, {:EMAIL => "invalid_email"}
    assert_response 500
  end

  test "valid signup" do
    gb = Gibbon::API.new
    gb.any_instance.stubs(:subscribe).returns(200)
    post :signup, {:EMAIL => "my_email@something.com"}
    assert_response 200
  end
end
```

But still is doing a call to the API.

Answer (score 2):

I'm used to RSpec (not TestUnit/Mocha), so I'm not all too familiar with the correct syntax here.

However, I do notice that you need to stub `any_instance` of `Gibbon::API`, so I'm guessing `Gibbon::API.any_instance` is what you need at least. Besides that, you'll need to stub both the `lists` as well as the `subscribe` method.

So, I'm guessing something like this should work in your `valid signup` test case:

```
lists = stub(subscribe: stub)
Gibbon::API.any_instance.stubs(:lists).returns(lists)
```

I don't think you'll have to return `200`, since that's what the render does.

Comment: hi @newmediafreak, I've tried your answer but I got this error: test_valid_signup(SomeControllerTest):
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError: object references itself. I'm looking why.

Comment: after reading this: github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/78 I did some changes Gibbon::API.any_instance.stubs({:EMAIL => "test_email@email.com"}).returns(lists) but I'm still hitting the MailChimp API and that is what I want to avoid.... sorry the delay in the answer of the MailChimp API it made me think that his answer was correct...